# Create a circular masked image then place it on another image in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-requests

How do you add a circular mask for an image in Python, then take that image and put it on a second image with a solid background.

Code:

```
import cv2
import requests as rq

r = rq.get(url, stream=True) # get image from url

if r.status_code == 200:
    resp = r.raw
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# define circle
radius = min(ht,wd)//2
xc = yc = radius

# draw filled circle in white on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros((ht,wd), dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (xc,yc), radius, 255, -1)

# create blue colored background
color = np.full_like(img, (255,0,0))

# apply mask to image
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# apply inverse mask to colored image
masked_color = cv2.bitwise_and(color, color, mask=255-mask)

# combine the two masked images
result = cv2.add(masked_img, masked_color)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('lena_circle_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('lena_circled.png', result)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('masked image', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: How can I do the same thing but my mask image is a circle, and not a square with a hole in it like in your example?

Comment: Post your exact mask and image.

Comment: Never mind that, I want to do exactly what you've done in your example, but with a transparent background.

Comment: Just take my circular mask and put that into the alpha channel of the image.